# Laravel 9 storage error 403 Forbidden

Tags: laravel, storage, error-403

Buen día.
Llevo un par de días con un problema que no me había pasado en ningún otro proyecto de Laravel.
Utilizo Angular y Ionic(angular) para conectarme a un VPS donde esta alojado mi proyecto Laravel 9. Ya ejecuté el comando `php artisan storage:link` y le di permisos 775 a la carpeta storage.

En este mismo VPS tengo mas proyectos Laravel donde subo imagenes con Storage de esta misma forma que en este proyecto

`request()->file('file')->store('public/'.$id);`

Esto guarda correctamente la imagen y la puedo ver en mi carpeta storage.

Ya cuando quiero ver desde algún navegador o desde la app esa ruta donde esta la imagen me marca el error `403 Forbbiden You do not have permission to access this document.`
La ruta que uso es con esta estructura:

`https://dominioejemplo.com/storage/1/ejemploimg.png`

Pero si vuelvo a darle permiso 775 ya muestra la imagen sin ningun problema, pero las nuevas imagenes que se suban no se mostrarán y seguirán diciendo `403 Forbbiden You do not have permission to access this document.`

No puedo estar dandole permiso 775 cada vez que se sube una nueva imagen ya que es un proyecto que lo manejaran decenas de personas.

Lo mas extraño que solo en **laravel 9** tengo este problema porque en mis proyectos pasados laravel 7, 6, 5.8 todos los proyectos suben imagenes y solamente tuve que dar permiso a la carpeta storage una sola vez.

Comment: le diste permiso pero tambien debes de cambiar el usuario y grupos propietario de la carpeta raiz de tu sitio a www-data, usa el comando *sudo chown $USER:www-data -R /etc/apache2/www/TU_SITIO*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viendo las configuraciones del sistema veo que actualmente el FileSystem_Disk estaba configurado en `local` y esto hace que no pueda ser mostrado en a menos que se le den permisos al archivo.

Cambiando a `public` se soluciona el problema y todos los archivos que se suban ahora estarán disponibles.

Cambiar en el archivo `.env` la variable `FILESYSTEM_DISK=public`

Answer (score 1):

anteriormente tuve este problema realmente desconozco si es un error comun o solo fue suerte pero la forma en la que dejo de salirme ese error fue:

---

> recuperar el archivo mediante el controlador.

> crear un nombre en otra variable en mi caso uso **Str::uuid()** para minimizar mucho lo que es la repetición de nombres.

> genero en otra variable la dirección en la cual voy a guardar la imagen y concateno el nombre antes generado.

> al final guardo guardo el nombre de la imagen en una BD ya sea solo nombre o la dirección completa ya eso depende de tu preferencia en cuanto al manejo de la información y cómo manejas el paso anterior y este.

Answer (score 0):

YO TENGO LA RESPUESTA!
Eso me pasa cuando no corro el "php artisan storage:link" desde la sesion que estará usando tu LARAVEL.

Lo que hice fue:

1. elimina el acceso directo que se genera con este comando, está en la carpeta "public" de tu proyecto.
2. ve al terminal de tu servidor y ejecuta el comando:

   php artisan storage:link

Eso creará de nuevo el acceso directo con los permisos y todo lo requerido...

Recuerda que Laravel va a un acceso directo llamado "storage" en la carpeta publica, para poder ir a storage sin dejar abierto a otras carpetas, ya que la carpeta "STORAGE" se encuentra al mismo nivel de carpetas que los archivos del framework...

espero haber ayudado :D